# How do I change which class I am calling variables from via string? c#

Tags: c#

I appreciate that in the following `"Class"` as a variable is incorrect. I am only using it to try and ask how is this actually done?

**Code in theory:**

```
public class Manager
{
    public string questionClassName;
    string question;
    string answer;
    Class questionClass;

    public void createQuestion()
    {
    questionClassName = "Lions"; //Set the name of the class I want to use as a string
    questionClass = questionClassName; //Select the class being used by name via string
    question = questionClass.question; //Question now set as the question from that class
    answer = questionClass.answer; //Same logic for answer
    Console.WriteLine("Question " + question + " Answer: " + answer); //Output
    }

}

public class Lions
{
    string question = "Which gender has the mane?";
    string answer = "Male";
}

public class Elephants
{
    string question = "Do elephants have tusks?";
    string answer = "Yes";
}
```

- I am trying to store lots of questions in separate classes as strings. I then wish to select between these classes to display their specific questions via a Manager class.
- Changing the string `questionClassName` in the Manager class to the name of one of the classes (Lion or Elephant in this example), would cause the Manager to display the questions and answers held within that class.

(I know I could just store these questions and answers all within the manager script in dictionaries for example but there's over three thousand questions across many categories with variables other than strings included. This is a fictional and 'as basic as possible' example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it the way you have designed it is through *reflection* which is messy. I would suggest that rather then making each question a separate *class* that you have a single class that represents an abstract question, and then store all questions in a data structure that's easily indexible by name:

> I know I could just store these questions and answers all within the manager script in dictionaries for example but there's over three thousand questions across many categories with variables other than strings included. This is a fictional and 'as basic as possible' example.

I don't see how creating a separate class for each question is more scalable. You could have separate subclasses for your "categories" depending on the attributes of each category that are unique, but having three thousand classes with very limited scope seems worse.

Comment: The classes (e.g Lion)are the topic and would each contain at least 100 questions. I only put one in the example here to try and keep things short. Thank you for your help, should I scrap this logic (you mentioned reflection being messy) and instead just make one class that contains all questions as the solution?

Comment: That would be cleaner than reflection - but without more concrete examples it's hard to say for certain what the best structure would be. Maybe a `Category` class that contains multiple `Question` objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of classes based on their name by using reflection:

```
var questionClass = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyApp.Lions");
```

That assumes the `Lions` class sits in the `MyApp` namespace.